# Regex that matches anything except for all whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I need a (javascript compliant) regex that will match any string except a string that contains only whitespace. Cases:

```
" "         (one space) => doesn't match
"    "      (multiple adjacent spaces) => doesn't match
"foo"       (no whitespace) => matches
"foo bar"   (whitespace between non-whitespace) => matches
"foo  "     (trailing whitespace) => matches
"  foo"     (leading whitespace) => matches
"  foo   "  (leading and trailing whitespace) => matches
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try searching for this first?

Comment: Yeah I did, totally forgot about the negated version of \s though.. doh! Thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: Instead of using regex, you could also test `if (str.trim()){ //matches }`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This looks for at least one non whitespace character.

```
/\S/.test("   ");      // false
/\S/.test(" ");        // false
/\S/.test("");         // false


/\S/.test("foo");      // true
/\S/.test("foo bar");  // true
/\S/.test("foo  ");    // true
/\S/.test("  foo");    // true
/\S/.test("  foo   "); // true
```

---

I guess I'm *assuming* that an empty string should be consider whitespace only.

If an empty string *(which technically doesn't contain all whitespace, because it contains nothing)* should pass the test, then change it to...

```
/\S|^$/.test("  ");      // false

/\S|^$/.test("");        // true
/\S|^$/.test("  foo  "); // true
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this expression:

```
/\S+/
```

\S mean any non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\s*\S+(\s?\S)*\s*$/
```

demo :

```
var regex = /^\s*\S+(\s?\S)*\s*$/;
var cases = [" ","   ","foo","foo bar","foo  ","  foo","  foo   "];
for(var i=0,l=cases.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(regex.test(cases[i]))
            console.log(cases[i]+' matches');
        else
            console.log(cases[i]+' doesn\'t match');

    }
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PNtfH/1/

Answer (score 2):

[Am not I am]'s answer is the best:

```
/\S/.test("foo");
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
/[^\s]/.test("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myStr.replace(/\s+/g,'').length){
  // has content
}

if (/\S/.test(myStr)){
  // has content
}
```