# RegEx for matching any char except only white-space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-negation

I am writing a php class to extract data from csv file. So I need help in regular expression.

**data sample**

```
Data 
Data        
Datatest1
Data test
Data         867$33@!.//()7
Field somthing
Field
```

**Regular Expression**

```
/(?:Data|Field)(.+)/
```

This should not match line 1,2 and 7 because it have only space and tab (whitespace) after Data and Field

here is my regex tester link
https://regex101.com/r/xpG25l/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex that matches anything except for all whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947866/regex-that-matches-anything-except-for-all-whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
(?:Data|Field)\h*\S.*
```

to require an `\S` (*non white-space character*) after any amount of `\h` (*horizontal space*).

[See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/xpG25l/3)

Comment: i also want to capture non white-space string after Data and Field

Comment: @Sunny for capture use [capturing group like this](https://regex101.com/r/xpG25l/4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative  lookahead `(?!\h*$)` to assert what is on the right is not 0+ times a horizontal  whitespace character `\h*` followed by the end of the string `$`

```
(?:Data|Field)(?!\h*$).+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xIuqyi/1)

If you regex should start matching from the start of the string you can append `^` to the pattern to assert the start of the string.

Or else in the string `test Field somthing` there will be a match for `Field somthing`