# How to say, in a group match, "except if only whitespaces"?

Tags: regex, whitespace

I would like to match text between quotes, but only if it consists of text and not only whitespaces.

In other words

```
hello world "this is matched" bonjour
```

should match `this is matched`, but

```
hello world "   " bonjour
```

should not match anything.

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947866/regex-that-matches-anything-except-for-all-whitespace) was almost what I wanted, except that it uses JS to make the test (this is also my current workaround in Python). OP's comment mentions negating `\s` but I do not think it was used anywhere (except as a comment)

Is there a simple way to add such a condition to the regex `"(.+)"`?

Answer (score 2):

You might also use a capture group matching at least a single non whitespace char other than `"`

```
"(\s*[^\s"][^"]*)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `"` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\s*[^\s"]` Match optional whitespace chars followed by a single non whitespace char other than `"`
  - `[^"]*` Optionally match any char except `"`
- `)` Close group
- `"` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVkEfh/1)

If there can be escaped double quotes, you might use an approach as also demonstrated in [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s answer, matching any char except `"` or `\` and allow matching an escaped character.

```
"(\s*[^\s"][^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfQhia/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex (assuming your quotes are all balanced and unescaped):

```sh
(?<=")\s*[^"\s]*[^"\s][^"\n]*(?=")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGM5sG/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=")`: Assert that we have opening `"` just before current position
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `[^"\s]*`: Match 0 more of any character that are not `"` and not whitespace
- `[^"\s]`: Match a character that is not `"` and not whitespace
- `[^"]*`: Match 0 more of any character that is not `"`
- `(?=")`: Assert that we have closing `"` ahead

---

If you input may contain escaped quotes like `\"` then I would suggest using:

```sh
(?<=")(?!\s*")[^"\\\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\n]*)*(?=")
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/UdXuZe/1)

Answer (score 1):

This matches text within quotes, excludes the quotes, and is a no-match if there are only spaces within the quotes:

```
(?<=")(?!\s+")[^"]*(?=")
```

Examples:

```
hello world "this is matched" bonjour ==> match
hello world "singleWord" bonjour      ==> match
hello world "" bonjour (empty)        ==> match
hello world "  " bonjour (spaces)     ==> null
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=")` - positive lookbehind for `"`
- `(?!\s+")` - negative lookahead for 1+ spaces and a quote

  - if you want to have a no-match for empty text between quotes use `(?!\s*")`
- `[^"]*` - scan over all chars until just before quotes
- `(?=")` - positive lookahead for quotes

Comment: @WoJ: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?